# 2 questions on elementary probability and stats

Tags: probability, statistics

1)A hospital ward contains 15 male and 20 female patients. Five patients are randomly chosen to receive a special treatment. What is the probability that the sample contains at least 1 patiens of each sex? At least two patients of each sex?

2)If $X$ follows $exp(\lambda)$, then $Y = aX + b$ follows exponential as well, but with what $\lambda$ and condition for $x$?

So for the 1st problem, I know how to calculate $P(M\geq 1)$ and $P(F\geq 1)$, but how do I calculate the probabilities asked? I know that they are not independent, so I can't multiply them, so is there a quick way?

Comment: Please try to stick to one topic per posting. Other than both being questions about probability, the two you asked have little to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when asked for the probability of at least something it is easier to do the opposite probability, in your case the opposite of the probability of at least take one male and one female is the probability of taking all male or all female, so the probability you are looking for is $P(\text{at least 1 of each sex})=1-(P(\text{5 males})+P(\text{5 females}))$.

For your second question develop $P(Y \leq y)$ and try to write it like the distribution function of an exponential.

Comment: 1) So, for the 2nd probability, I can do P(at least 2 of each sex) = 1- (P(4M) + P(5M) + P(4F) + P(5F))?

Comment: Yes, thats it, I highly recommend that whenever you are stuck in a probability problem try if it is easier to get the propability of the opposite situation.

Comment: You want to see what $Y=aX+b$ follows so you have to calculate $P(Y \leq y)=P(aX+b \leq y) = P(X \leq \frac{y-b}{a})= \ldots$